# SQL -- Counting with nested subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, associations

I have a collection of tables in a relational database

- `products`
- `categories`
- `orders`
- `line_items`
- `customers`

Products has a many-to-many relationship with categories (join table `categories_products`) and also has and belongs to many `orders` through `line_items`, which is a join table for `products` and `orders` with an id. A `customer` also has many `orders`.

I'm trying to put together some SQL that will give me this sort of response:

```
    customer_id | customer_first_name | category_id | category_name | number_purchased
    -----------------------------------
    1 |Jack | 1 | Electronics | 15
    2 |Jill | 1 | Electronics | 2
    2 |Jill | 2 | Hiking | 3
```

This is the giant hunk of SQL I've been trying to use to get these values:

```
    SELECT 
            DISTINCT customers.id AS customer_id,
            customers.first_name AS customer_first_name,
            categories.id AS category_id,
            categories.name AS category_name,
            (
                SELECT count(li.id) FROM line_items li
                INNER JOIN orders o ON li.order_id = o.id
                INNER JOIN products p ON li.product_id = p.id
                INNER JOIN categories_products cp ON cp.product_id = p.id
                WHERE
                    o.customer_id = customer_id 
                    AND o.status = 3
                    AND cp.category_id = category_id
            ) AS number_purchased
        FROM orders
        LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
        LEFT JOIN line_items li ON li.order_id = orders.id
        LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = li.product_id
        LEFT JOIN categories_products catpr ON catpr.product_id = products.id
        LEFT JOIN categories ON catpr.category_id = categories.id
```

Only the count itself is wrong. Instead of getting the number of line items a customer has bought in a specific category, I'm instead getting a count for all LineItems that have been part of a completed order.

How can I get the count to correctly represent the number of `line_items` purchased by a specific `customer` within a `category`?

NOTE: in the SQL text, `o.status = 3` is using an enum to indicate that an Order is "complete."

Comment: Your query looks like it's specific to category. Will removing `number_purchased` return a similar output?

Comment: I suggest adding group by's

Comment: @RudyM `number_purchased` is the only value that is returning incorrectly. I could theoretically obtain the `number_purchased` value in separate queries for each combination of `customer` and `category` or at the code level, but I'm specifically trying to write a single SQL statement to output all of this info correctly

Comment: @PapaPoison , so for Jill, you're getting 3 for both rows ?

Comment: @RudyM, no, I'm getting the first row, Jack's count of 15, for all rows.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your inner join with `categories_products` is screwing this up. You should set up a fiddle, like @Strawberry suggested, or try this:

```
SELECT 
        DISTINCT customers.id AS customer_id,
        customers.first_name AS customer_first_name,
        categories.id AS category_id,
        categories.name AS category_name,
        (
            SELECT count(li.id) FROM line_items li
            INNER JOIN orders o ON li.order_id = o.id
            INNER JOIN products p ON li.product_id = p.id
            WHERE
                o.customer_id = customer_id 
                AND o.status = 3
        ) AS number_purchased
    FROM orders
    LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
    LEFT JOIN line_items li ON li.order_id = orders.id
    LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = li.product_id
    LEFT JOIN categories_products catpr ON catpr.product_id = products.id
    LEFT JOIN categories ON catpr.category_id = categories.id
```

Comment: Okay, this comment got me most of the way there. One extra detail that helped get it all the way right was that in the subquery I used `customer_id`. Replacing that with the original `customers.id` instead ensured that the correct values were passed to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to correct your count, I would advise using a GROUP BY clause in the subquery. If you GROUP BY orders then you will only get the specific order which you retrieved when looking that the user id was correct. I would encourage you to take a look at mistakes in other part of your SQL code to clean up this hulking query. For example, make sure you want to be using distinct and that you actually want to be using left joins versus inner joins, both of which could seriously mess with the performance of your program.

Comment: What do you mean when you say GROUP BY orders?

I added a GROUP BY statement to the subquery (`GROUP BY o.id`), which makes the _first_ count correct, but each subsequent row incorrectly uses the same count.

For example, `customer1` has an order with 3 `line_items`/`products` with the `category` "Electronics". The `number_purchased` column is counted as 3 -- correct for this first row. However, `customer2` has an order containing 2 `line_items`/`products` with the `category` "Books". The count is still coming back as 3 when it should be 2. Any insight there?